# Gitlab CI cannot find sonarqube coverage report, does work locally

Tags: angular, sonarqube, gitlab, sonarqube-scan

I have an angular application deployed via gitlab ci. The deployment to the hosted Sonarqube instance does go through although none of the code coverage reports show up unfortunatly

My gitlab yml file is as follows

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

unittests:
  image: markhobson/node-chrome:latest
  stage: test
  variables:
    NODE_ENV: development
  before_script:
    - npm install
  script: 
    - npm run test
    - npm run sonar


production:
  type: deploy
  stage: deploy
  image: ruby:latest
  script:
    - echo "Heroku api key = $HEROKU_API_KEY"
    - echo "Heroku appname = $HEROKU_APP_NAME"
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_NAME --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  only:
    - master
```

And my sonar-project.properties file is as follows

```
sonar.host.url=HOSTURL

sonar.projectKey=SONARKEYNAME
sonar.login=
sonar.password=
sonar.projectName=SONARKEYNAME
sonar.gitlab.project_id=GITLABURL

sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=/coverage/client/lcov.info
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=/coverage/client/lcov.info

# --- optional properties ---
sonar.projectVersion=0.0.1
sonar.exclusions=client/node_modules/**, node_modules/**
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.verbose=false
sonar.working.directory=.scannerwork

sonar.projectBaseDir=.
sonar.sources=./src/app
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.exclusions=node_modules/**,**/*.spec.ts,**/*.css
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
```

Whenever I deploy the application via the CI I get the following message:

```
Provided LCOV file path: coverage/client/lcov.info. Seek file with the path: /builds/USERNAME/REPONAME/coverage/client/lcov.info
No coverage information will be saved because all LCOV report files cannot be found.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this error and why it doesn't occur when running sonar scan locally (without the CI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search it turned out that, code coverage was not enabled in the `angular.json` settings. I added the following under `"test"`:

```
          "options": {
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "main": "src/test.ts"
           }
```

The coverage shows up properly with gitlab CI and running the command locally

Comment: You also can run the test with the option :
  `--code-coverage`